# Passing scoped state in runST function

Tags: haskell

I have a test function like below which uses `runST` to internally mutate state. I defined another function `go` within it which returns `Int` wrapped in `ST` as result (just playing with some `ST` concepts). The problem is that my type signature for the function seems to be wrong. If I comment out the function type signature, code runs fine. With type signature as in the commented code, it doesn't compile because the compiler  interprets the state of the `go` function as different from the state in enclosing scope. I will appreciate pointers on how to define the function type signature to pass outer `ST s` to `go` function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Main where
import Data.Word(Word32)
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as U hiding (mapM_,create)
import Control.Monad.ST as ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimState)
import System.Random.MWC

test :: Word32 -> Int
test x = runST $ do
     gen <- initialize (U.singleton $ fromIntegral x :: U.Vector Word32) :: (forall s. ST s (Gen (PrimState (ST s))))
     let --go :: Int -> ST s Int
         go x = do
            v <- uniformR (1,x) gen
            return v
     i <- go 100
     return i
```

This is the compiler error I get if I uncomment type signature `go :: Int -> ST s Int`:

```
Couldn't match type `s1' with `s'
  `s1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for go :: Int -> ST s1 Int at A.hs:12:16
  `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
      a type expected by the context: ST s Int at A.hs:10:10
Expected type: Gen (PrimState (ST s1))
  Actual type: Gen s
In the second argument of `uniformR', namely `gen'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: v <- uniformR (1, x) gen
In the expression:
  do { v <- uniformR (1, x) gen;
       return v }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trouble is that when you say

```
gen <- ... :: (forall s. ST s (Gen (PrimState (ST s))))
```

`s` is now *fixed* to whatever `s` `runST` provides -- i.e. we cannot consider it a type variable as your signature would have you believe[1].  When the compiler says "rigid type variable", this is what it means.  To reinforce that it is fixed, let's refer to it as `S1` for this answer.

Notice that

```
let go :: Int -> ST s Int
```

is equivalent to

```
let go :: forall s. Int -> ST s Int
```

i.e., `go` must work for *any* `s`.  But then you say

```
v <- uniformR (1,x) gen
```

which attempts to bind a computation of type `ST S1 <something>`.  `go` is supposed to work with *any* `s`, not just `S1`, so this is an error.   The correct signature for `go` is `Int -> ST S1 Int`, but of course we just made up `S1` for argument's sake, and the true `S1` has no name in the source file, so `go` cannot be given a signature, even though it is well-typed.

[1] Oh, you have `ScopedTypeVariables` on, so it looks like the `forall` is there because you are trying to scope `s`.  That doesn't work -- scoped variables only apply to the body of the function with the `forall`.  You can solve this by moving the signature to the left of the `<-`:

```
(gen :: Gen (PrimState (ST s))) <- initialize ...
```

after which `s` will be properly scoped.

Comment: moving the type definition as you suggested, fixes the issue. However, I am not clear why it has to be moved that way. So, leaving it open for now.

Comment: @Sal, it's because of how ScopedTypeVariables work.  You can bind a type variable with `:: forall s. ...` or in a lambda binding, such as `\(x :: [a]) -> {- a is bound here -}`.  Monadic bind desugars to lambda binding.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but I can make things work by also passing `gen`:

```
test :: Word32 -> Int
test x = runST $ do
     gen <- initialize (U.singleton $ fromIntegral x :: U.Vector Word32) :: (forall s. ST s (Gen (PrimState (ST s))))
     let go3 ::  (Num b, Variate b) => Gen (PrimState (ST s)) -> b -> ST s b
         go3 g x' = uniformR (1,x') g
     go3 gen 100
```

Comment: Yep, that is obvious workaround for lack of scoping...I did that before, and want to avoid it. Hence, this question.